# Change x axis limits when using factor for geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to increase the x axis limits by 1 on both sides when using factors as your x-axis scale. For instance, in the following plot is it possible to change the xlimits to 3 and 9? i.e. `xlim(3,9)`

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_boxplot()
```

When trying `xlim()` I get:

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

And when I try `scale_x_continuous(limits = c(3,9))` I get:

```
Error in if (zero_range(from) || zero_range(to)) return(rep(mean(to),  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In loop_apply(n, do.ply) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In loop_apply(n, do.ply) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In loop_apply(n, do.ply) :
  position_dodge requires constant width: output may be incorrect
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want `scale_x_discrete`:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_boxplot() + scale_x_discrete(limits = c("4","6"))
```

or `xlim`:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_boxplot() + xlim("4", "6")
```

Edit: asked to include wider range. To include other values, you need to use the breaks function, on a list of factors:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_boxplot() +
    scale_x_discrete(breaks = factor(3:9), limits = c("3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```

In this case, you will have to plot out the 8 cyl boxplot, unless you give a fake 8:

```
p + geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=factor(c("3","4","5","6","7", "eight", "9")),
                   limits = c("3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "eight", "9")
```

or filter it out before plotting:

```
mtcars<-mtcars[mtcars$cyl!=8,]
```

Reference: [scale_x_discrete](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_discrete.html)

Comment: Is it possible to make the limits lower than 4 (3) and higher than 8 (9) without getting an error? The reason for doing this is to line it up with a bar plot.